# How to force Visual Studio to NOT use the dedicated GPU but only the integrated graphics?

Tags: visual-studio, gpu

Is there any way to configure Visual Studio 2017 to **not** use the dedicated GPU but only the integrated graphics?

TL;DR

The particular problem is with my laptop which has a faulty dedicated graphic card, while its integrated graphic card is fine. And whenever the dedicated one is in use, I get the machine frozen with beautiful pink or brown, or green, or etc. screen. So waiting for the service, before replacing the GPU I would like to be able to work on my Visual Studio.

The question is related to the programming IDE, so I decided to put it on StackOverflow.

Comment: it's more related to https://superuser.com/ I think you can just remove graphic card or disable it in Windows.

Comment: I had already tried disabling the graphic card via Windows Device Manager but it prevented Visual Studio even from starting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tools - Options - Environment - General uncheck **Use hardware graphics acceleration if available**:

[image]